# Unit testing a method that writes serialized objects to a file

Tags: java, unit-testing, serialization, junit

I have a static method that writes serialized object. How can I write JUnit tests to see if it works? Here is my method...

```
    public static void writeToDisk(Data data){

     try{
            FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(filename);                             ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(fis);
            dataList = (DataList) in.readObject();
            in.close();         
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            dataList = new DataList();
            System.out.println("New file created!");
        }

        dataList.insertData(data);

        try{
            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(filename);
            ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);
            out.writeObject(dataList);
            out.close();
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        }   
    }
```

Comment: You dont need to test that method, it has obviously missing error handling and it is not crash safe. BTW: it should be named "appendDataOnDisk" or similiar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start with no file.

Call the method with test `Data` argument. Then read it back from resulting file (pull data from list as needed) and compare to original.

Repeat with new objects to see if new data is added successfully.

Comment: How do I test the case if there is a file and I dont need to create a new file?

Comment: If that's a case, save your sample file in some location known to test, copy it to temp location at start and use it. You will need to parameterize filename in your code so your method knows to write to sample in temp location.

Answer (score 1):

Change your function to accept an InputStream. In production, pass a FileInputStream, in tests, pass a different InputStream which you can then check to make sure it contains the correct value.